# Anyone with experience on django-preferences app or similar?

Tags: django, django-admin

Im still trying to embed a page in my admin site where I can let the user to change some global variables (like in wordpress) such as the site name, meta keywords, etc.

Apparently there is an app that does this but I cannot get it to work (Im using Django 1.3):
http://github.com/praekelt/django-preferences

NOTE: I tried both `from preferences.model import Preferences` and `from preferences.models import Preferences` it still cannot find the Preferences object.

Many thanks!

Comment: Make sure the preferences module is either directly in your application or is in the python path.

Comment: You're using Django 1.3? It's not even released yet (it's due for alpha release next Monday - http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/sep/30/django-1_3-release-schedule/).

Answer (score 1):

The docs were incorrect, it should read:

```
from preferences.models import Preferences
```

[I've corrected the docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-preferences).

As Andrew suggest though it looks like your problem is caused by the module not being correctly installed. If you don't mind installing it as a system wide module, run the following:

```
$ easy_install django-preferences
```